# Display MySQL Results vertically in terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal

Is there a way to show data from the table in a more clean way?
For example:
`SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;` shows a clean display of each column with the type of data it contains and this information is displayed vertically.

[image]

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE uid=99999;`
However, when I select one record from this table, the results are jumbled because the screen is not wide enough for a clean view. Is it possible to display the columns on the left instead when just looking at one row?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, after I figured out how to word my question, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134569/how-to-show-records-vertically-in-mysql-command-line

Comment: u deserve self-learner badge :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The \G modifier in the MySQL command line client**

A little publicized, but exceedingly useful feature of the MySQL command line client is the `\G` modifier. It formats the query output nicely, so you can read through it easier. To use it, you just replace the semi-colon at the end of the query with `\G`.

For example,

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000193 |     7061 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: mysql-bin.000193
        Position: 7061
    Binlog_Do_DB:
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `mysql` to do this automatically by configuring it in a `my.cnf` file

```
[mysql]
  auto-vertical-output
```

This way, you can continue to use `;` as a statement terminator, and any query output that exceeds the terminal width will automatically switch to the vertical mode.

This can be a hassle when the output switches that way when you don't want it, e.g. output from a `mysql -Bse '...'` command that you want to pipe to something else.

In that case, you override the the auto switching with `mysql --auto-vertical-output=false ...`